# easy php array of images, from a WordPress custom field

Tags: arrays, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, custom-fields

I'm trying to use 1 custom field for a bunch of images - to do the same thing to all the images. I can store them in the custom field however is advisable, but I thought this format would be best, since I think that's what a PHP array goes into:

```
'http://images.domain.com/image1-Th.jpg',
'http://images.domain.com/image1-Th.jpg',
'http://images.domain.com/image3-Th.jpg'
```

So, once I have my custom field values entered for a post, here's my non-working PHP code:

```
<?php //og images
    $ogimagepre = '<meta property="og:image" content="';
    $ogimagepost = '"/>';
    global $wp_query; $postID = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $photosfull = array(get_post_meta($postID, 'custom_field_name', true));
    echo $ogimagepre.$photosfull.$ogimagepost
?>
```

You can see I'm trying to get this result:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.domain.com/image1-Th.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.domain.com/image2-Th.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.domain.com/image3-Th.jpg"/>
```

That's Step1. Ideally, I'd be able to do other things using the same array. Such as replace "-Th.jpg" with "-X3.jpg", since that's a larger size of the same image. And other stuff; need to get past Step1 first.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `get_post_meta` call return an array of image URLs? Not sure if I'm understanding the setup correctly.

Comment: The function is described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta - It just returns the value, not specifically in an array to my understanding. But I thought if I entered 'image1.jpg','image2.jpg',etc into the custom_field_name then it would already be "formatted" as a PHP array. If there's a better way, no problem. I'm just trying to avoid haveing 1 custom field per image - extra maintenance for me and extra database calls. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted images under a single meta key to be returned as unique elements. Try this:

```
$ogimagepre = '<meta property="og:image" content="';
$ogimagepost = '"/>';
global $wp_query; $postID = $wp_query->post->ID;
$photos =get_post_meta($postID, 'custom_field_name', true);

foreach ($photos as $photo){

    echo $ogimagepre.$photo.$ogimagepost
}
```

Comment: Hey, great stuff man. Thanks a LOT! I was wanting help right away so we're working on it over here: http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/2848